# Sourcing a bash script does not error when pipelined with &&

Tags: bash

I'm finding that sourcing the following bash script does not cause the a sequence of commands to stop when pipelined with `&&`.

**sourceme.sh:**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -o errexit
set -o | grep errexit

echo "About to error from sourceme.sh..."
$(false)

echo "sourceme.sh did not exit on error (exit code: $?)"
```

This is the call to demonstrate the problem.

```
(source sourceme.sh && echo "sourceme.sh did not error (exit code: $?)")
```

The output I get from this is as follows.

```
errexit         on
About to error from sourceme.sh...
sourceme.sh did not exit on error (exit code: 1)
sourceme.sh did not error (exit code: 0)
```

This is the opposite of what I expected, where I expected to see the the whole command die when `$(false)` is reached in `sourceme.sh`, producing the following outout.

```
errexit         on
About to error from sourceme.sh...
```

Continuing the bizarreness, if I use `;` in place of `&&`, then I would expect the command continue, but this is not what happens.

```
$ (source sourceme.sh && echo "sourceme.sh did not error (exit code: $?)")
errexit         on
About to error from sourceme.sh...
```

So when sourcing the file `&&` behaves as I expect `;` to behave, and `;` behaves as I would expect to `&&` to behave.

Where am I going wrong with my understanding of how this should work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea, roughly stated, is that `set -o errexit` (or, equivalently, `set -e`) causes the shell to exit on **uncaught** errors.  The fact that `&&` follows `source sourceme.sh` means that the error is caught.

So, if the `source` and `echo` commands are connected with `;`, the shell exits:

```
$ (source sourceme.sh ; echo "sourceme.sh did not error (exit code: $?)")
errexit         on
About to error from sourceme.sh...
```

But, if the `source` and `echo` commands are connected with `&&`, then the shell assumes that you have anticipated the possibility of the `source` command failing and the shell does not exit:

```
$ (source sourceme.sh && echo "sourceme.sh did not error (exit code: $?)")
errexit         on
About to error from sourceme.sh...
sourceme.sh did not exit on error (exit code: 1)
sourceme.sh did not error (exit code: 0)
```

Much of the behavior of `set -e` may be considered odd or unexpected.  For more examples, see [Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

#### Documentation

The behavior of `set -e` (errexit) is defined more precisely in `man bash`:

> **-e**
> Exit  immediately  if  a  pipeline  (which  may consist of a single simple command), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL
>   GRAMMAR       above), exits with a non-zero status.  The shell does
>   not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list
>   immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test
>   following the if or elif reserved words, part of any command executed
>   in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||,
>   any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the  command's  return 
>   value  is being  inverted  with !.  If a compound command other than a
>   subshell returns a non-zero status because a command failed while -e
>   was             being ignored, the shell does not exit.  A trap on
>   ERR, if set, is executed before the shell exits.  This option applies
>   to the shell               environment  and  each  subshell 
>   environment  separately  (see COMMAND EXECUTION ENVIRONMENT above),
>   and may cause subshells to exit           before executing all the
>   commands in the subshell.
>                      If a compound
>   command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being
>   ignored, none of the  commands  executed  within  the
>   compound command or function body will be affected by the -e setting,
>   even if -e is set and a command returns a failure status.  If a
>   compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a
>   context where -e is ignored, that setting will not  have  any  effect 
>   until the compound command or the command containing the function call
>   completes.

#### Synonyms

As documented in `man bash` as well as in `help set`, the following two commands are equivalent:

```
set -e
set -o errexit
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out the relationship between -e and -o as the original script uses -o.  Oop: it's there. :)

Comment: @Gerik OK.  I added a section documenting that the two are equivalent.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks John. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are observing is this.

This command doesn't exit on error:

```
(source sourceme.sh && echo "sourceme.sh did not error (exit code: $?)")
```

However this command:

```
(bash sourceme.sh && echo "sourceme.sh did not error (exit code: $?)")
```

does exit so `&&` is not the only reason of this weirdness. It is combination of `source` and `&&` that makes it not to exit.

You have also noted that use of `;` instead of `&&` makes it exit as in  following command:

```
(bash sourceme.sh && echo "sourceme.sh did not error (exit code: $?)")
```

**This behaviour is actually dependent of bash version in use.**

When I run this command on OSX `bash 3.2.57(1)-release` **it does exit**:

```
(source sourceme.sh && echo "sourceme.sh did not error (exit code: $?)")
```

```
errexit         on
About to error from sourceme.sh...
```

However **on bash versions `4.2` and above behaviour changes** and `set -e` doesn't exit when used with `&&`.

So bottomline is that `set -e` is highly unreliable and one should avoid depending on it's behaviour in important shell scripts.